# How many major revisions are allowed when publishing with Elsevier?

Tags: publications, elsevier

I submitted my paper to one of the Elsevier journals in the field of molecular biology and evolution, I've got one major revision back; I fixed the comments, and sent it back to the journal.

It is still "under review" for 1.5 months.

What I want to know is

- Is it possible that this review comes out with another major revision?
- how many major revisions can I get?
- what are usually the time frames for the second round of reviews?

Comment: Several rounds of major revisions are certainly possible.

Comment: It's completely up to the editor. The publisher is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

To give this an answer:

1. Yes, it is posisble that you are again asked to make major revisions.
2. It's completely up to the editor to decide how many rounds of revisions are appropriate.  There's not a fixed number for all the publisher's journals.
3. You'll have to ask someone in your field, ideally someone who's published in that journal before.  But it also depends a lot on how speedy the reviewer is, and how long the editor gives them.

Comment: Although I believe @Nate Eldredge is right, in that it's up to the editor, I do believe myself that the editor should have a very good reason to require more than one major revision - I've had a few cases where I felt that multiple 'major revision' steps were actually a mechanism for delay.